# In C++, is there overhead in the first function call made?

Tags: c++

I was playing around with profiling certain things in C++ and I came across this very weird thing that I don't have an explanation for. Basically, the first function call made in main always takes significantly longer than any subsequent calls. This makes me think that the first function call has some kind of overhead. I'm not sure what this overhead would come from, so if anyone has any insights on why this is happening, I'd appreciate it. Also, I'm using Clang++

The a simple code snippet that shows this point is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

const int size = 1000000;
using namespace std;

void foo() {
    int arr[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        clock_t t = clock();
        foo();
        t = clock() - t;
        cout << "cycles: " << t << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output shows that the first call always takes about 2000 more cycles than the rest of them

```
cycles: 5185
cycles: 3049
cycles: 2981
cycles: 2830
cycles: 2851
cycles: 2767
cycles: 2694
cycles: 2570
cycles: 2517
cycles: 2490
```

Comment: I suspect that the OS lazily loading in code pages is responsible for this.

Comment: Unless this is compiled with optimizations enabled none of this data is meaningful.

Comment: @tadam I tried optimizations off and on and on a few different compilers and they gave me similar results.

Answer (score 3):

My thought is that in the first function call the function code itself is loaded up into memory like the L1 Cache and then the function code is executed. By the next function call, the function code will already be in the cache, so the CPU wont have to spend cycles doing that and it can just run the function again. This is why the first call to foo takes longer than the rest.

Also, note that calling another function whose code is next to foo in memory can bring foo into memory as well since the OS loads pages of memory at a time. I've tested this and it seems to sometimes work, so take that with a grain of salt. I guess the compiler makes it non deterministic where the binaries of function definitions are located. So it's possible for the function code to be in cache before the first time you call it, but if not, it'll take a few extra cycles to put it there before the CPU actually runs the code.

Comment: Also, the CPU is usually basically idle. When you start a tight loop, it'll increase it's clock speed, so the computer actually _gets faster_ after a few calls

Comment: This is not an answer, this is speculation.

Comment: Your results look like you're timing unoptimized code.  The optimizer should recognize that no observable result is used, and can optimize _all_ of it away.  However, unoptimized code tends to be big and bloated, which also supports your hypothesis of it being a cache effect loading the function.  There is also the branch predictor in the cpu that may play out, where it "learns" your loop during the first call.

Comment: @Chris I never thought of the branch predictor as a reason for this, but that's pretty cool. I've tested this on unoptomized and optimized compilations and they give me similar results. though.

Comment: @JoshuaSegal  Are you sure? https://godbolt.org/z/M96fEvx9d

Comment: It's not the small function code but the memory associated with `int arr[size]` Once cached, subsequent accesses are quicker.

Comment: @doug this is very interesting. Are you saying the first function call to foo allocates the arr[size], but then subsequent calls use the same array and thus don't need to allocate it again? Wouldn't the function stack be erased after the first call to foo finishes and then the next call would have to allocate arr[size] again?

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis I meant similar results like the first call is longer than the subsequent. But yeah, optimizing it does decrease those cycles by a lot

Comment: No. The hardware has no idea initially what is allocated. But when the memory is accessed by writing to addresses, it will get moved to cache. Given how large it is, it will likely end up in L3, or L2 if there are only two levels. Writes to main memory will be much slower than the loop but writes to L3 cache, which will be propagated to  main memory, will be faster. The loop will restart before L is finished writing to main memory.  All this really depends on the specific hardware. Check your system and post the L1,2,3 sizes.